# About the period of "from the turn of the decade"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning

When you use "from the turn of the decade", that means from `1990`, `2000` or `2010`, right?

Or is it also OK to use the "decade" for the middle number like `2003~2013`?

Comment: A decade can refer to any period of ten years, yes.  So you could say "the decade 1955-1965".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decade means a time period of 10 years. You could say something like:

> I quit that job last decade.

Now this is 2016, you actually quit the job in 2009. Technically it was just 7 years ago. But you can still say it that way. But you cannot refer *'2003-2010'* as a decade because that's only 7 years. However, say you were a vegetarian and you quit meat in 2003 and that went on till 2010. Now, you could say that:

> I was a vegetarian last decade.

That doesn't mean you were a vegetarian for 10 years. So that is okay. But you cannot refer 7 years as a decade. Hope this helped.

Comment: Yes, but if say you were a vegetarian from `2010` onwards, in `2016` you could still say that you had been a vegetarian since the turn of the decade because '2010' was the start of a new decade.

Comment: Yes, if you started being a vegetarian since 2010, you can definitely say that, at any point till 2020 ( 23:59 on 31/12/2019 to be more precise, haha).

Answer (score 2):

The turn of a [timespan] means the time around the point where one named [timespan] "turns" into another named [timespan].

It's ordinarily used with centuries: the turn of the 20th century is the time around the point where the 19th century ended and the 20th century began. A turn of a decade would work the same way: the turn of the 1990s would be the time around the point where the 1980s ended and the 1990s began.

But the phrase isn't used for random points in time: just for points where generally recognized names change.

Answer (score 0):

I Do not agree that the decade ended at 0h00 on 31 December 2019; In my humble opinion, the decade started 1 January 2011 and will continue until 31 December 2020; If we go back to the terms acronyms BC and AC, it implies that the 1st decade started in year 1 until year 10; and the 2nd decade started from year 11 until year 20; Fast forward to the current Decade, It therefore stands to reason that the current decade started on 1 January 2011 and will end on 31 December 2020

Comment: Copying the OP's question, "Is it okay to use the "decade" for the middle number like 2003-2013?" You might want to check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decade